# How to Patent Artwork Plus Captioning

Tags: patentability, design-patent, inventorship

I have an idea for a T-shirt design. It involves artwork plus captioning. Do I have to patent the artwork and the captioning separately? How does one afford such patents?

Answer (score 2):

Patents cover inventions. Neither an artwork nor captioning are inventions, and so would not eligible for a patent. You may be thinking of copyright, which covers creative works. If so, that's off topic here, so your question would be better asked [thataway](http://law.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Bonus: (Non registered) Copyright doesn't cost money.